# Creating a 2x2 table of binary variables

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table based upon two variables: trade intensity and military spending. These are integer values, but I have created a dummy variable so that they are split into either being above (1) or below the mean (0) for each country.

I want a table that looks like the below, and pulls up the Country Name! Basically all the 1s and all the 0s go into the appropriate boxes.

```
                      Low Trade          High Trade
Low Military Spend    xxx, xxx, xxx      xxx, xxx

High Military Spend   xxx, xxx           xxx
```

Is this at all possible? I cannot figure out how to do this at all.

Many thanks, N

Comment: Please provide an example of your data with the dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. First I make up some data to use.

```
library(dplyr)

example_of_your_data <- 
  tibble(country_name = paste("Country ", LETTERS), 
         milex_dummy = sample(c(0, 1), 26, replace = TRUE), 
         trade_dummy = sample(c(0, 1), 26, replace = TRUE))
```

`example_of_your_data` looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 26 x 3
   country_name milex_dummy trade_dummy
   <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Country  A             1           0
 2 Country  B             1           1
 3 Country  C             1           1
 4 Country  D             1           0
 5 Country  E             1           0
 6 Country  F             0           1
 7 Country  G             1           0
 8 Country  H             1           1
 9 Country  I             0           1
10 Country  J             1           1
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Then I convert your dummy numeric variables to factors and summarize your data into a long format:

```
example_of_your_data %>% 
  mutate(military = factor(milex_dummy, 
                           labels = c("Low Military Spend", 
                                      "High Military Spend")), 
         trade = factor(trade_dummy, 
                        labels = c("Low Trade", 
                                   "High Trade"))) %>% 
  group_by(military, trade) %>% 
  summarize(country = paste(country_name, collapse = ", ")) -> tbl_long
```

Then I construct the matrix.

```
with(tbl_long, {
  matrix(country, 
         nrow = 2, 
         byrow = TRUE, 
         dimnames = list(levels(military), 
                         levels(trade)))
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great and provides the format I want BUT how do i get country names in the tables? Code below:
tibble(country_name = LETTERS, 
       milex_dummy = factor(sample(c("Low Military Spend", "High Military Spend"), 26, replace = TRUE)), 
       trade_dummy = factor(sample(c("Low Trade", "High Trade"), 26, replace = TRUE))) %>% 
  group_by(milex_dummy, trade_dummy) %>% 
  summarize(country_name = paste(country_name, collapse = ", ")) -> tbl_long

with(tbl_long, {
  matrix(country_name, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(levels(milex_dummy), levels(trade_dummy)))
})

Comment: Thank you! However, I have 140 countries in my list - is it possible to do it like this? I also wanted the eventual table to pull up the actual Country Names, not a code, but assuming this isn't possible due to this error? Error: Column `country_name` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 14

Comment: All of your questions and that error have more to do with how you have your data structured than the code to make the table. For me to help further, you need to share how your data are structured. Please edit your question to copy and paste the output of `dput()` used on your data object(s).